# C++ unix time from Mysql DateTime string

Tags: c++, mysql, parsing, datetime

I'm using the official Mysql C++ driver and I'm attempting to read a mysql datetime string and parse it into a unix timestamp in c++.

I realize that I can use the unix_timestamp(column_name) function from within mysql, however, my specific instance requires that I parse the string from c++.

This is what I have attempted

```
static long UnixTimeFromMysqlString(std::string &s)

{

struct tm tmlol;
strptime(s.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tmlol);

time_t t = mktime(&tmlol);
return t;

}
```

The result that I am getting from this function does not appear to be correct.  The input string is a standard mysql datetime string. Ex. 2013-06-06 13:37:42.

Does anybody have experience doing this?  Thanks

Comment: what makes you think that it's not working?

Comment: The value that is returned doesn't appear to be a valid timestamp.  It was ridiculously large.

Comment: It's supposed to ... time() returns the time as the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC).

Comment: You can convert it to a string like this:   time_t ret = UnixTimeFromMysqlString(str);
  cout << "It is now " << ctime(&ret) << endl;

Comment: Just added `time_t ret = 0; localtime_r(&ret, &tmlol);` after declaring tmlol to initialise tm_gmtoff/tm_isdst. Apparently, made some difference to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have already works - you can test it by looking at:

```
  string str = "2013-06-06 16:06:00";
  cout << UnixTimeFromMysqlString(str) << endl;

  time_t current = time(NULL);
  cout << current << endl;
```

When I ran it I got:

```
1370549160
1370549171
```

To see it as a string you can do:

```
  time_t ret = UnixTimeFromMysqlString(str);
  cout << "It is now " << ctime(&ret) << endl;
```

Which produces output:

```
It is now Thu Jun  6 16:06:00 2013
```

Comment: Oops it looks like your right.  The first time I ran this, something else must have been going on.  Thanks for your confirmation!